# If else in #define macro directive ... error: expected expression before ‘if’

Tags: c, macros

Cant I use `if/else, if/else if/else` in `#define` directive? Below code gives errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define makro(a) if(a%2 == 0) 1 else 0;

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int a = makro(5);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}

prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:3:18: error: expected expression before ‘if’
 #define makro(a) if(a%2 == 0) 1 else 0;
                  ^
prog.c:7:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘makro’
  int a = makro(5);
          ^
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with macros. `if` is not an expression in C. Read a beginner C book/tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. That macro expands like this

```
int a =  if(a%2 == 0) 1 else 0;
```

And obviously that isn't legal. You could try this (using a ternary). Also note that this bitwise and is equivalent to the modulo 2 from before.

```
#define makro(a) ((((a) & 1) == 0) ? 1 : 0)
```

of course you could [shorten](http://ioccc.org/) it a little more to

```
#define makro(a) (!((a) & 1))
```

Comment: +1 But I would remove semicolon (or it'll give another error if used in an expression) and I would add parenthesis around parameter (if parameter is an expression itself) and around all macro (same reason, it may be used in a complex context).

Comment: The `==` will evaluate to 1 or 0 in exactly the right way here, so the entire `?:` is redundant technically, although I guess  it helps clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the problem if you unpick the macro:

```
int a = if(5 == 0) 1 else 0;
```

This is clearly syntatically incorrect (`if...` is a *statement* not an *expression*).

You can replace the `if` with the *ternary* (which is an *expression*):

```
int a = 5 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

and, reforming to the macro gives you a correct definition:

```
#define makro(a) ((a%2) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

I've also introduced parentheses in case `a` is a function, an expression like `c++` etc.

**Expression Statements**

As a final remark, if you are using GNU C, then you could use *expression statements* which is a non-standard C extension. Then you get your `if...` statement back again. See

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

for more details.

Comment: That semicolomn should be removed I guess, as I explain above. By the way +1 for the final remark

Answer (score 1):

You should define the macro like this:

```
#define makro(a) do { (a%2 == 0) ? 1 : 0; } while (0)
```

or

```
#define makro(a) ((a%2 == 0) ? 1 : 0)
```

putting semicolomn at the end of a macro is almost always a bad idea because for example you get in trouble writing:

```
printf( "Val %d", makro(a) );
```

if you put the semicolomn

This macro can be better defined as:

```
#define makro(a) ((~a)&0x01)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ternary operator](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-conditional-operators/) in this case.

```
#define makro(a) ((a) % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already there so better see that there are 2 points to note here :

1. A macro in the code is actually an inline expansion of its definition, as it is. Also,  dont put semicolons after macro  definition for that very reason.Also, enclose the entire macro definition within parantheses for correctness.

   e.g. #define add(a) a+a

   when used like add(2)*add(3) will be 2 + 2 * 3 + 3 =11

   and not the expected 4*6=24.

   2.If and else do not form a single statement , they are 2 statements connected together.

   ie.   if(2) --something--; else --something---; is correct.

   Its not like the do while loop where do and while are  a single    statement.

   #include

   int main()

   { if(0)  ; //---------> If and else are separate staements

   else printf("Hello\n");

   return 0;
     }   is a correct program.